# Convert code into customised PDF

Tags: matlab, pdf, export

Is there an easy possibility to convert/export MATLAB code into a customised  PDF without using the publish feature of MATLAB?

I want to convert my code output into a PDF with Name, Date, etc...

Comment: ...and why not use the publish function?

Comment: As far as I know there is no possibility for Publish just for the output of my code added with logos, names etc.

Comment: You could try publishing to HTML, use a custom CSS and imagery, and convert it all to PDF using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) or so...I don't see this working in an "easy" way, and probably not without using third party software..

Comment: I don't think this is easy but if you have MS Word/Excel you could learn to use activex in Matlab to export your code to a MS Word template and convert from PDF from there...here's an example: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94822-are-there-any-examples-that-show-how-to-use-the-activex-automation-interface-to-connect-matlab-to-ex

Comment: My aim was to do that automatically. So that I run the code and at the end of that MATLAB would print a PDF giving out a PDF with all settings from me (figures, data, date, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tool of choice will probably be LaTeX with either the `listings` or the `minted` package. This allows you to use any existing LaTeX style files, e.g. university templates and so on. You can easily style the document, and the MATLAB code the way you like.

Right here, I describe a manual way, which is not automated yet: Create a document e.g. `matlab-docu.tex` with the following content, and some MATLAB script `testscript.m` which you want to export. Note, I use the `matlab-prettifier` package, which is an extension to the `listings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{My awesome MATLAB code}
\author{Homer J. Simpson}
\date{\today}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{style = Matlab-editor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{testscript.m}
\lstinputlisting{testscript.m}

\end{document}
```

Then, you can compile this to a PDF using the `pdflatex` command. You can do that from your favorite LaTeX editor, or directly from MATLAB by calling

```
!pdflatex matlab-docu
```

Of course, you can automate this as much as you like, e.g. by creating this `matlab-docu.tex` file automatically from MATLAB.

The output of the above example is shown below:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Wow. That is very helpful! Thank you very much for your efforts mate! Much appreciated.